# Alternative way to retrieve request.params.<>

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform

```
var objectKeys = Object.keys(request.params);
for(var i = 0; i < objectKeys.length; i++){
        var key = objectKeys[i];
        object.set(key, request.params.key);
}
```

I want to set the object values using keys I retrieved from the `request.params` from Parse Cloud. However, the `request.param.<>` takes the value without using .get from the key. For example to get a "name" key would be `request.params.name` and not `request.params.get("name")`.

I am always getting a value of undefined as `request.params.key` is actually getting a "key" key and not "name" which value does not exist. Is there any way I can achieve this without add a whole chunk of code?

Answer (score 1):

Okay for people that might need this. This gets the value in the request.params[]

To get a "name" key from request.params would be request.params["name"]

```
for(var key in request.params){
    object.set(key, request.params[key]);
}
```